# In moodle sent email to only passed students in quiz

Tags: moodle

In moodle 2.7, I want to sent email to only be passed to student with quiz result information! Have any already plugins or customization?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable and is built-in to Moodle.

In the context of a single quiz:

1. Go to Administration > Quiz Administration > Permissions
2. Find where it says "*mod/quiz:emailconfirmsubmission*", and click on the plus sign next to it.
3. This will take you to a screen where you have a drop-down menu titled "Select Role" - Select "Student".
4. Click on "Allow"

---

If you want to change the content of the message, you'll need to do that through Administration -> Language customisations. The language tags is "*emailconfirmbody*".

---

This is very thoroughly documented **[here](https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Quiz_submission_email_notification#Allow_confirmation_messages_to_students)**.